# Implement custom Builder with Lombok

Tags: java, lombok

I want to use custom setter in Lombok's builder and overwrite 1 method, like this

```
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public class Teacher extends User {
}


@Data
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)
public class User implements Employee {
    private static final PasswordEncoder ENCODER = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    private String username;

    private String password;

    public static class UserBuilder {
        public UserBuilder password(String password) {
            this.password = ENCODER.encode(password);
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

but I have this compilation error

```
Error:(17) java: type User.UserBuilder does not take parameters
```

Comment: Where does it show that error? I'd expect it to appear in a place where you use the `UserBuilder`.

Comment: on the Teacher class , in the @SuperBuilder annotation

Comment: I gave all the information you need in an extensive answer to your last question. However, you accepted the wrong answer. Did you read my answer at all?